# Powershell script for ping

Tags: powershell, ping

I have list of servers and NAS devices on the network.  All listed with a csv file with NAS_List(column B) and Server_List(column A) headers.  I want to ping using column A to column B.

```
Server_List           NAS_List
Server12345 pings    NAS12345
Server23456 pings    NAS23456
Server34567 pings    NAS34567
```

I also want to get an output of this in txt/csv format to future.  Hope I'm making sense :)

Thank you 
Bhavin

Comment: have a look at `test-connection` and come back when you have a specific problem . https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. The above list doesn't look like a csv=comma separated list you could easily `Import-Csv filename.csv`

Comment: Like Paul said, have a play around with `test-connection -source $Var1 -destination $Var2` and post your results. We can troubleshoot as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) to serialize your CSV data in an array-object. After that you can loop over that array via the [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object?view=powershell-6)-cmdlet. In the loop you can call [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Test-Connection?view=powershell-6) to "ping" the given server.

I've uploaded a simple function on [github](https://github.com/moerwald/stackoverflow_powershell-script-for-ping).

```
function Ping-Servers{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    # Load CSV data to local object
    $servers = Import-Csv .\servers.csv

    $testResultArrayWithDictionaryAsContent = $servers | Foreach-Object{ 
            #Iterate over the CSV rows
            Write-Information "Testing $($_.Servers)"
            #Call "ping" and store the result
            $ctResult = Test-Connection $_.Servers; 
            # return a dictionary for every CSV row (including the ping result)
            @{ Nas = $_.Nas; Server = $_.Servers; TestResult = $ctResult }}
    $testResultArrayWithDictionaryAsContent 
}
```

Check the [Powershell about sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/powershell-scripting/hh847856(v=wps.640)), they offer cool stuff of information. If you're complete new to Powershell you should the FREE MVA [Getting Started with Powershell](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/getting-started-with-microsoft-powershell-8276?l=i0y5HPWy_4404984382) course. Though this course handles Powershell 3.0 its an excellent entry point in the Powershell world.